# Is there an “Application.Wait” method

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I’m trying to make a macro in VBA that translates from English to Spanish all the text in the PowerPoint text objects and I found a method that do that in excel but it uses the Application.wait method that only works in excel, is there another way to pause the PowerPoint program? I’ve never used VBA before, sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: What does it use `Application.Wait` for?

Comment: I think that it is because it needs time to make the consult in the google translate page but I’m not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this instead if you cannot get `Application.Wait` to work

```
Sub AppWait()
  Dim WAIT As Double
  WAIT = Timer
  While Timer < WAIT + 2 ' 2 seconds
    DoEvents  'do nothing
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked but couldn’t make work other features of the script with PowerPoint